# Gerar um relatório usando thread em segundo plano

Tags: delphi, thread, relatório

Quero gerar um relatório, mas quero que o sistema fique liberado para o usuário fazer outras atividades enquanto não tem o retorno do relatório. Para isso estou usando thread, só que quando eu fecho o formulário está dando erro porque a thread necessita de informações do formulário e como ele foi fechado ele não está mais na memória.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Na thread você pode fazer uma nova implementação do `constructor` onde você passará todos os dados que a mesma necessite, de forma a ficar independente do form, que ao ser destruído, não comprometerá a execução da Thread.

Fica assim:

```
interface
  TRelatoriorThread = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create(const aParam1: string; aParam2: Integer...);
  end;

implementation
  constructor TRelatoriorThread.Create(const aParam1: string; aParam2: Integer...);
  begin
    inherited Create;
    FParam1 := aParam1;
    FParam2 := aParam2;
    ...
  end;
```

Assim você prepara a thread e ela executa de forma independente do objeto que a iniciou, pode ser form, datamodule ou qualquer outra coisa que um dia venha a existir.